# What does formAction() method in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I'm confuse with these lines of code...

where it goes after clicking submit button??

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="updateForm()"/>
```

Comment: You probably have a function somewhere, in your page or an imported script, with name "updateForm". This function would be called.

Comment: if you have `<form action="submit.php"></form>` around your code, you will submit your form to that page on your webserver.  
But first the code in the updateForm() function will execute, and if you put `return false;` there (eg for validation purposes) your form will not submit

Comment: @PieterWillaert: that's only true if `type="submit"` which is not the case here

Comment: @PieterWillaert not on clicking that button.

Comment: actually there was no line of code when I read the question :) but ofcourse you're right. Since the op mentions `formAction()` I think he wants to achieve something like I said before

Comment: @PieterWillaert I guess the function sends an AJAX instead of navigating. Otherwise a `submit` would make much more sense.

Comment: There are all sorts of things the script could do. It might just do some number crunching entirely on the client side.

Answer (score 4):

`onClick="updateForm()"` means that when the button is clicked call the method `updateForm()`. Look for a method by that name in the source code.

<s>If updateForm() returns a `false`, then the default behavior of the button is suppressed. If not, then `updateForm()` is called, following which the button proceeds with its default behavior.</s>

Comment: The button has no default behaviour to suppress … and it doesn't matter what `updateForm` returns because `onClick` doesn't capture it and make use of it (as, for example, `onClick="return updateForm()"` would)

Comment: -1. Default behaviour is **not** suppressed by any return value of `updateForm()` when it's used in this way.

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

An event handler function (the body of which is defined by the value of the `onclick` attribute) runs. That function does nothing except try to call another function `updateForm`.

What happens next depends on the definition of `updateForm`.

Comment: Technically speaking, is the caller of `updateForm` visible in the stack trace?

Comment: Why the downvote? This _is_ technically correct.

Comment: @JanDvorak — Yes, http://imgur.com/za4ZQ

Comment: still should be noted that said event handler is the evaluated body of the `onclick` argument.

Answer (score -3):

formaction method??

You can also Use one of the below mentioned behaviours:

```
<form id="myform" action="javascript:myfunction();">

<form onSubmit="return myfunction()">*
```

Now you can describe your function in your javscript file:

```
myfunction=function (){
```

// My code goes here

}

When you submit your form "myFunction" will be called first and then your subsequent form behaviour will be seen or you can prevent its behaviour by returning false in your function.